How come Selenium's Seebeck Coefficient is higher than that of Tellurium?
A little heads up: I came across a Science Mag article on Thermoelectric Materials (Focus was on SnSe (tin selenide). Loved how it sort of spells "Sensei" - this is beside the point) today on one of my Socials and this led me to take a small dive into this topic.
I've come to learn about the Peltier–Seebeck Effect and what intrigued me is the Seebeck coefficient ($\mathbf{S}$) for Selenium which, of course, led to the question:

"Would the EMF generated by SnSe be improved when we have SnTe (tin telluride) instead?

After a little digging, I found out that $\mathbf{S}_\mathbf{Se} \gt \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{Te}$. Which now led to a new question:

Why is there this "large" difference in Selenium and Tellurium?

and a newer one:

Could it be a result of their electron configurations? Have I made an error in assumption?

I'd really appreciate a refresher on this topic.

Do you understand where the Seebeck voltage comes from? While it is interesting that Te has about twice the Seebeck coefficient as Se, isn't it more interesting that Te has about a 1000 times the Seebeck coefficient of Pt?

@JonC I think you have that the wrong way around.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient

@PM2Ring - sigh, yes (Se > Te)...  Now, one clue to consider is that the hole mobility in Se is higher than Te.

@JonCuster from what I've come to learn is that during Peltier cooling, the thermal energy is induces an e.m.f on the conductive material which is then referred to as the Seebeck Voltage.

Also @PM2Ring, it turns out Jon was correct in stating $\mathbf{S}\mathbf{Te} > \mathbf{S}\mathbf{Se}$. I did some digging and got some insight from this book:
"Thermoelectrics: Basic Principles and New Materials Developments" by David M. Rowe
It turns out that PM and I got "jebaited" once again by Wikipedia.
David goes on to say that $\mathbf{S}$ tends to increase as we descend the Chalcogen Group.
AND
Yes Jon Custer, I find that relation between Te and Pt most interesting.

Thank you both for your contributions.
